# Overlay a Fragment over existing Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, fragment-tab-host

I have a design of `TabLayout` or `TabHost` which ever you want to consider. Suppose this are the tabs -

Tab1 | Tab2 | Tab3 | Tab4 | Tab5

In this following action will take place -

1. Tab1 - opens Fragment1
2. Tab2 - opens Fragment2
3. Tab3 - opens an **overlay** over existing fragment with a translucent black view
4. Tab4 - opens Fragment3
5. Tab5 - opens Fragment4

Any idea about how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!!

**UPDATE: Solution I used**

I tried this, but had to make lot of customization. So I stopped in middle as it was hell lot of work. So another way around I did is I put one more view over the `TabLayout` on exactly same position as of Tab3 and on click of that `View` I made the overlay view visible.

Comment: Are you using a `ViewPager`?

Comment: ya currently using `ViewPager`

Comment: how is this supposed to work when user scrolls pages via swipe? should the overlay swipe from the side on top of the current page? or tab 3 is ignored during the swipe

Comment: I have disabled swipe in that. It behaves like `TabHost`

Comment: But thats out of question, design is like overlay from middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewPager` is not designed for this use case. Tabs automatically map to their corresponding element in the `ViewPager`. But here's how I could see it kind of working.

1. Have a `TranslucentOverlayView` that has `Visibility.GONE` which overlays your entire `ViewPager`.
2. Have tab3 open a duplicate clone of `fragment2`, and when `tab3` is selected, make the `TranslucentOverlayView` visible. This does mean that you'll have two separate instances of `fragment2` side by side though.

Comment: good suggestion will try this out...!! thanks :) will vote up once I implement it

Comment: check the question. I have updated it with answer. Thanks for suggestion. It would have surely work, if I had time to implement it :)

Answer (score 1):

As @ZakTaccardi said, `ViewPager` is not designed for this.

However, I would try creating a `FragmentPagerAdapter` with 5 pages. I mean, `getCount()` should return 5. If the current index is 2, then you should return the instance that is currently on the screen. That means, your adapter should know what the current page is. You can use `ViewPager`s `onPageChangeListener` to let the adapter know what the current page is. To retrieve an instance use `FragmentManager`. Don't store the reference to fragment in the adapter because this will cause a memory leak. This is to prevent duplicated fragments when you select tab 3.

To display an overlay, implement a `View` on top of your `ViewPager` and display it in `onPageSelected()` callback of the `ViewPager` when the position is 2. Hide it when the position is not 2.

Comment: check the question. I have updated it with answer. Thanks for suggestion. It would have surely work, if I had time to implement it :)

Comment: You should post it as an answer, not as an update to your question. Then you will be able to accept it and this question will be considered as "answered". At the moment it's still open. Thank you.